# Recover lost photo from Instagram stories

Tags: photos, instagram

I took a photo to upload Instagram Stories but I have deleted it unintentionally without publishing or saving it when I was editing the photo in Instagram's built-in photo editor.

Is it possible to recover this photo?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The photos are saved in a folder of cache. If you are root user you can recovere them. There are in the next path: /data/data/com.instagram.android/cache/original_images